# Robocopy batch file to move and zip folder and output log

Tags: batch-file, backup, 7zip, robocopy, logfile

This is what I currently have:

```
ROBOCOPY C:\A\move\Logs C:\A\move\moved /MOVE /S /MINAGE:5 /log+:output.log
for /d %%X in (*) do (
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "LOG"%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4%Backup.zip" "%%X\" 
pause
```

I am having a some trouble trying to setup the batch to zip the Destination folder into a zip file using 7zip. any suggestions or help?

Comment: What have you got so far, friend?

Comment: what is your command that you are running? something similar to `7a a -tzip C:\A\move\moved\archive.zip *.txt`? This would archive all .txt files in the current dir to the `...\moved\archive.zip` as a zip file.

Comment: ROBOCOPY C:\A\move\Logs C:\A\move\moved /MOVE /S /MINAGE:5 /log+:output.log
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "LOG"%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4%Backup.zip" "%%X\"

pause

//So far I'm able to move the files properly But I'm not able to put the output folder into a .zip and remove the files when they are completed.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question with the code in the question. I cant take a look at it more until I'm home though.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with this:

```
@ECHO off
SET "7ZIP=c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe"
SET "FROM=C:\A\move\Logs"
SET "TO=C:\A\move\moved"
SET OUTPUT=output.log
SET DD=%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4%

if not exist %7ZIP% ECHO No 7z && GOTO :END

ROBOCOPY %FROM% %TO% /MOVE /S /MINAGE:5 /log+:%OUTPUT%

for /d %%X in (*) do (
  "%7ZIP%" a -tzip "LOG_%DD%_%%X_Backup.zip" %%X
)

:END
pause
```

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to call 7zip to do its thing. If I take out the 7zip functionality. I still am able to get it to do about half of what I need. I also changed the Minage to 14 as the files I'm working with are getting older... :)

@ECHO off
SET "FROM=C:\A\move\Logs"
SET "TO=C:\A\move\moved"
SET OUTPUT=output.log
SET DD=%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~-4%

ROBOCOPY %FROM% %TO% /MOVE /S /MINAGE:14 /log+:%OUTPUT%

Comment: You can get it working.  It is just a simple matter of getting the command line options to the 7za command correct.  So, just fix those things and try again.  I made edits to the above script; please take note.